# How to replace the onpaste function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

An input element on a web page is defined like the following to prevent passwords being pasted in:

```
<input type="password" class="field" id="password" name="password" title="Enter your password" maxlength="50" onpaste="javascript:return false;" size="38" tabindex="2">
```

I want to enable pasting in this input field. Using Firebug or equivalent I can edit the onpaste function so the code is:

```
onpaste="javascript:return true;"
```

This is fine for me, but for other users, I want a simpler solution. What came to mind is that if I could give them some Javascript, they could open the console and paste in a simple one-liner. However when I tried to do this the Javascript had no effect. I tried the following and neither worked.

```
$('#password').onpaste=""
$('#password').onpaste="javascript:return true;"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $('#password').on('paste', function(e){ return true; });

Comment: I assume your `$` is jQuery; please correct the tags if that is not correct.

Comment: Am I missing something? Why can't you just *not* put the onpaste attribute there?

Comment: @Anonymous I thought the same thing, but the OP is dealing with an input that is currently set not to allow pasting, but they want to enable pasting again

Comment: @JuanMendes Ah, my bad, I thought they were talking about their own input element. That makes more sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to combine jQuery with regular JavaScript. You can just use pure JavaScript to remove the onpaste listener.

```
document.getElementById('password').onpaste=""
```

If you want to use jQuery instead, you can use:

```
$('#password')[0].onpaste=""
```

which would give the same result.

Comment: Now excuse my ignorance, what is wrong with mixing jQuery and Javascript? Surely jQuery just get the element "password" and then we can use regular Javascript on the element ?

Comment: jQuery is returning its own object that stores a reference to the element. What you need is the element itself. The jQuery object has certain properties attached to it, but onpaste is not one of them.

Comment: So can I turn a jQuery object back into a "regular DOM object" (sorry I'm sure I'm getting the terminology horribly wrong here!!!!)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've discovered that $('#password')[0].onpaste="" would have the same effect. Thank you @Anonymous for the solution and the explanation.

Comment: @Phil Yes, it would, but I always prefer to use pure JavaScript. :)

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the `onpaste` attribute of the [DOM element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element), not of the [jQuery object](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/) which does not have a `onpaste` property. Your code is creating a property (set to a string) that is just being ignored.

In the example below, you can click the button and paste will be re-enabled.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('password').removeAttribute('onpaste');
})
```

```html
<input type="password" class="field" id="password" name="password" title="Enter your password" maxlength="50" onpaste="javascript:return false;" size="38" tabindex="2">

<button>Allow pasting</button>
```

Comment: this extension skips the onpaste restriction https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dont-fuck-with-paste/nkgllhigpcljnhoakjkgaieabnkmgdkb

Comment: @humano But it's kind of useless unless you can get all users of your website/webapp to install it. Requiring a plugin for your app seems like a bad idea

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#password').onpaste=""
$('#password').onpaste="javascript:return true;"
```

Are not valid functions. For firing event which comes from paste, you must write function like this

```
$('#password').bind("paste", function(e) {
    callback();
});
```

But solution for your question is here http://jsfiddle.net/9et20v36/, in `click` function from button `allow`, I remove `onclick` attribute from input which allows to paste text.

So for pure javascript use

```
document.getElementById('password').removeAttribute('onpaste');
```

or jQuery way

```
$('#password').prop('onpaste', null);
```

Comment: Ok, as a simple solution, how can I just clear the onpaste function? Is this valid: $('#password').bind("paste", null) ?

Comment: @Phil what do you mean by "clear"? Function which does nothing or which prevents from bubbling an event up...?

Comment: What I meant by clear was to remove all bound paste functions